# How to throttle background task based on InteractionManager?

Tags: react-native

I have a list of projects in a Redux store. When new location data arrives from the GPS I'm updating the distance to each project in the list. Currently I'm throttling the update to 5 second intervals.

If the update coincides exactly with a navigation transition (using Ex-navigation) I get a non-smooth transition.

I would like to throttle based on a time interval and on data from InteractionManager.

Here is the current code:

```
let throttledProjectUpdate = _.throttle((position) => {
  dispatch(ProjectState.projectNewLongLat(position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude))
}, 5000)

let watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
   dispatch(sensorGeoNewPositionAction(position))
   throttledProjectUpdate(position)
});
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
let throttledProjectUpdate = _.throttle((position) => {
  InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() =>
    dispatch(ProjectState.projectNewLongLat(position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude))
  );
}, 5000)

let watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
   dispatch(sensorGeoNewPositionAction(position))
   throttledProjectUpdate(position)
});
```

But a few things are stopping me:

1. Is this really possible? I.e is InteractionManager a singleton which I can require from everywhere?
2. It feels wrong to mix GUI stuff with my background state updating

How should I solved this?